# Identify what items in list were modified

Tags: list, workflow

I am trying to setup a workflow that alerts me when a list item in SharePoint has been changed. I don't need the actual value, just the field name that has been modified.

The closest I have come to this is `Add Lookup -> Current Item -> Modified By` but that only shows me who made the edits, not which fields were changed.

Is this something that can even be accomplished through workflows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can derive the fields in workflow email which are possibly changed or all the fields you want.

Here is a very high level description of the solution, as described [in this link](http://officepowerups.com/2013/07/09/send-email-when-specific-field-changes-in-sharepoint/):

1. Create a hidden helper column in the form. This column stores a copy of the field data that you wish to track (must be same data type).
2. In workflow, set a condition to compare the field value against its helper field value. If they are different, then a change has been made.
3. Alongside whatever other code you wish to execute, make sure that you update the helper column to the new field value in the workflow. Otherwise, the workflow will always think that the field has been changed.